# Why my Oracle 12c database seems not to be started?

Tags: oracle, connectivity, startup

I have installed an Oracle 12c database on my development environment, which I start only once a while for integration testing. But today, it does not seem to start, or did it start but does not allow connections? Here are some clues:

- OS is Debian 8
- I use a shell script to start and stop the database
- **$ORACLE_SID** contains

> INFO

- The **hosts** file contains

> 127.0.0.1 localhost and 127.0.1.1 Strada.nohoo.biz    Strada

- The **/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/info/INFO/alert_INFO.log** file ends with

> Completed: ALTER DATABASE OPEN Sun Mar 11 20:27:57 2018 Shared IO Pool
>   defaulting to 112MB. Trying to get it from Buffer Cache for process
>   4294.
>   =========================================================== Dumping current patch information
>   =========================================================== No patches have been applied
>   =========================================================== Sun Mar 11 20:27:57 2018 db_recovery_file_dest_size of 4560 MB is 0.00% used.
>   This is a user-specified limit on the amount of space that will be
>   used by this database for recovery-related files, and does not reflect
>   the amount of space available in the underlying filesystem or ASM
>   diskgroup.

- **tnsping** INFO returns

> TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on
>   11-MAR-2018 21:42:22
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Used parameter files:
>   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
>
> Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias Attempting to contact
>   (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT =
>   1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME =
>   INFO.nohoo.biz)))
>
> OK (0 msec)

- **tnsnames.ora** contains

> ```
> INFO =
>   (DESCRIPTION =
>     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
>     (CONNECT_DATA =
>       (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>       (SERVICE_NAME = INFO.nohoo.biz)
>     )
>   )
> ```

- **listner.ora** contains

> ```
> LISTENER =
>   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
>     (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
>     )
>   )
> ```

- **lsnrctl services** returns

> LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 11-MAR-2018
>   21:54:24
>
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connecting to
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
>
> The listener supports no services
>
> The command completed successfully

- The **ps -A | grep ora** command in a shell returns a list of

> 6003 ?  00:00:00 ora_pmon_info
>    6005 ?  00:00:00 ora_psp0_info
>    6007 ?  00:00:00 ora_vktm_info
>    6011 ?  00:00:00 ora_gen0_info
>    6013 ?  00:00:00 ora_mman_info
>    6017 ?  00:00:00 ora_diag_info
>    6019 ?  00:00:00 ora_dbrm_info
>    6021 ?  00:00:00 ora_vkrm_info
>    6023 ?  00:00:00 ora_dia0_info
>    6025 ?  00:00:00 ora_dbw0_info
>    6027 ?  00:00:00 ora_lgwr_info
>    6029 ?  00:00:00 ora_ckpt_info

But all this does not look like a successful situation!

And finally, trying to connect with SQLplus ends up with

> ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database seems to be up and running, but it was not registered dynamically into the listener.

Try the below:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=info

sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> show parameter local_listener
```

Check the value of local_listener. You have 3 options here:

1. parameter value is empty - in this case, the database registers itself into the listener running on port 1521
2. parameter value is something like `LISTENER_INFO` - this is a TNS entry that resolves to the address of the listener. If `tnsping LISTENER_INFO` resolves to a valid address, the database should be able to register itself to the listener specified by that
3. parameter value is something like `(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521))`. No name resolution is required, database registers itself in the listener.

You most likely have `2.` with an unresolvable name, or `3.` with and invalid network address.

You can try fixing it with:

```
alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))';
```

Which sets the specified address.

Or:

```
alter system set local_listener='' scope=memory;
alter system reset local_listener;
```

Which clears the value of `local_listener` in memory and spfile, so the database will try registering into a listener running on the default 1521 port.

If this still does not help, you can register your database in the listener statically, by adding the below in `listener.ora`:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
  (SID_DESC =
   (GLOBAL_DBNAME = info.nohoo.biz)
   (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
   (SID_NAME = info)
  )
 )
```

After that reload the listener:

`lsnrctl reload`

Or restart the listener:

`lsnrctl stop`
`lsnrctl start`

And try logging in again.